# SSH Tunnel doesn't work in Azure DC/OS Quickstart

Tags: windows, azure, ssh, ssh-tunnel, dcos

I've tried following the 5 minute quick-start to setup a Azure Cluster Service with DC/OS. Everything worked up until the SSH tunneling part.

The command runs fine, however when I try to go to the Control Panel the request seems to never get a response and just loads forever.

I've tried using PuTTY to make the tunnel as well as the OpenSSH feature that's installable on Windows 10 (which is what I'm on). Neither one seems to properly be able to forward the traffic.

I honestly have no clue what could be wrong as this is my first time setting up something like this.

Logging in to the DC/OS master does work and other commands seem to work just fine.

Comment: Just making sure you've seen the full [sshing docs](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.11/administering-clusters/sshcluster/) and not just the quickstart guide :)

Comment: Does that work for you? please show more details about your issue?

Comment: @JudithMalnick SSH'ing into the master does work. It's the tunneling that doesn't. I can't pull up the web interface.